# Add Another Context Root Simulate webseal - Websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, webseal, contextroot

I need to simulate the presence of a Load Balancer (WebSeal) in my local installation of WebSphere 8.5. In detail, when an application is exposed through webseal is added into the URL, before the Application Context Root, the webseal Junction name. For example, an application with context-root "myapp":

- Without webseal: localhost:8080/MyApp/......
- With webseal: localhost:8080/**JunctionName**/MyApp/......

So i need to simulate this because i have shared DB with common configuration between my local installation, without webseal, and test installation balanced by webseal.

There is the possibility to configure a common context-root that the AS have to add to the URL of the deployed app in WebSphere 8.5?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way for one app to have two context roots, but for your local installation testing purposes you might be able to install two copies of the app, one at each context-root.  It's probably a change to application.xml, or if you're deploying through the console UI, I think it's
 configurable there.